# Hide watermark code in original TeX-file possible?

Tags: watermark

Is it possible to distribute original TeX files to the public with a code that generates a watermark whenever the tex-file is rendered? 
Is it at least possible to make the code hard to detect?

Comment: Yes. Depends what you mean by 'hard to detect' and which members of the public are involved. I don't really understand the second question but if you distribute the code, you distribute the code. You can obfuscate it to some extent but why would you do that? (Why not just distribute the document without the source in that case?)

Comment: tex is a macro expansion language, you can obfuscate code for fun (like `xii.tex`) but you can't really obfuscate code to hide anything it would always be trivial to remove the watermark.

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one suffering under the delusion that we have to much copyright laws. But if I'm not completely wrong, the line "Copyright Love Learning 2014" in your tex file will do a better job than a watermark. If I'm wrong, please explain the purpose of the watermark you'd like to have.